# Flutter NFC on iOS not working, after pressing "cancel" in nfc-scan-popup

Tags: ios, flutter, plugins, nfc

I'm using the following plugin to read my nfc-tag: https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_in_flutter

First of all - great plugin!

I just have this problem, when pressing "Cancel" on this iOS NFC-Scan Popup (see picture below). 
When I press "cancel" nfc on the device is not working anymore. My thought is, that nfc is already be used by my application and needs to be released.

Here the piece of code, I'm starting to read the tag:

```
NFC.isNDEFSupported.then((bool isSupported) async {
  if (isSupported) {
    try {
      NDEFMessage message = await NFC.readNDEF(once: true).first;
      print(message.payload);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
});
```

So if I pressed "cancel" once and try to scan my nfc-tag again, I will get the following error:
**PlatformException(SessionTerminatedUnexpectedlyError, Session invalidated unexpectedly, null)**

[image]

Comment: did you get to solve this issue? Thx

Comment: Not yet. Will create a issue in the Gitlab repository.

Comment: This one seems the same issue: https://github.com/semlette/nfc_in_flutter/issues/29

Comment: @all, i have some queries. I see there are different type of tag/chips supported for iOS(MiFare, FeliCa, ISO15693)/Android ( NfcA, NfcB, NfcF). Does it mean, when i write data with Mifare , can not be read using Android/vice versa ? We are making flutter app, so both platform should support. How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of the nfc_in_flutter plugin.

I have released version 2.0.4 which should fix this issue. The fix was [submitted by another user](https://github.com/semlette/nfc_in_flutter/issues/29#issuecomment-572241500), but the problem was that the reading session was being invalidated before it was ready.